# how to prevent redirecting on register user in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, createuserwizard

hi i am using createuserwizard server control but facing little bit problem when ever i am registering user through this control it's automatically navigate and login to created user i don't want to that that on user creation go to automatically how can it would be possible any idea.

here is aspx code:-

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser" OnNextButtonClick="CreateUserWizard1_NextButtonClick">
                <WizardSteps>

                    <asp:WizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep0" runat="server">
                        <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;" class="MarginStyle">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h4 class="HeadingThemeColor align I18N">TitleAddTeacher</h4>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table cellpadding="10">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label ID="LblOrganization" CssClass="lblStyle I18N" runat="server">form.data.Organizations</asp:Label>
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DplOrganization" runat="server">

                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="DplOrganizationRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server"
                                                    ControlToValidate="DplOrganization" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Organization Name must Selected."
                                                    ToolTip="Organization Name must Selected." ValidationGroup="AddInstitution"><span class="err I18N">error.messages.Organization Name must Selected</span></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>

                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label ID="LblInstitutes" CssClass="lblStyle I18N" runat="server">form.data.Institutes</asp:Label>
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DplInstitutes" runat="server">

                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="DplInstitutesRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server"
                                                    ControlToValidate="DplInstitutes" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Institute Name must Selected."
                                                    ToolTip="Institute Name must Selected." ValidationGroup="AddBranch"><span class="err I18N">error.messages.Institute Name must Selected</span></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>



                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>

                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label ID="LblBranches" CssClass="lblStyle I18N" runat="server">form.data.Branches</asp:Label>
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DplBranch" runat="server">

                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="DplBranchRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server"
                                                    ControlToValidate="DplBranch" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Branch Name must Selected."
                                                    ToolTip="Branch Name must Selected." ValidationGroup="AddInstitution"><span class="err I18N">error.messages.Branch Name must Selected</span></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>

                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" CssClass="lblStyle I18N" runat="server">form.data.Marital Status</asp:Label>
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtMaritalStatus" runat="server" CssClass="txt" placeholder="Marital Status" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator16" runat="server"
                                                    ControlToValidate="TxtMaritalStatus" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Marital Status is required."
                                                    ToolTip="Marital Status is required." ValidationGroup="AddTeacher"><span class="err I18N">error.messages.Marital Status is required</span></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label5" CssClass="lblStyle I18N" runat="server">form.data.Company</asp:Label>
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtCompany" runat="server" CssClass="txt" placeholder="Company" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator17" runat="server"
                                                    ControlToValidate="TxtCompany" ErrorMessage="Company is required."
                                                    ToolTip="Company is required." Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="AddTeacher"><span class="err I18N">error.messages.Company is required</span></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label6" CssClass="lblStyle I18N" runat="server">form.data.Occupation</asp:Label>
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtOccupation" runat="server" CssClass="txt" placeholder="Teacher Occupation" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator19" runat="server"
                                                    ControlToValidate="TxtOccupation" ErrorMessage="Teacher Occupation is required."
                                                    ToolTip="Teacher Occupation is required." Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="AddTeacher"><span class="err I18N">error.messages.Occupation is required</span></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label7" CssClass="lblStyle I18N" runat="server">form.data.Passport Numer</asp:Label>
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPassportNumer" runat="server" CssClass="txt" placeholder="Teacher Postal Code" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator20" runat="server"
                                                    ControlToValidate="TxtPassportNumer" ErrorMessage="Teacher Passport Numer is required."
                                                    ToolTip="Teacher Passport Numer is required." Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="AddTeacher"><span class="err I18N">error.messages.Passport Numer is required</span></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label8" CssClass="lblStyle I18N" runat="server">form.data.Upload Image</asp:Label>
                                                <br />
                                                <br />
                                                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </asp:WizardStep>

                    <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;" class="MarginStyle">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h4 class="HeadingThemeColor align I18N">TitleAddTeacher</h4>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <table cellpadding="10">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="LblUserName" CssClass="lblStyle I18N" runat="server">form.data.UserName</asp:Label>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <br />
                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" CssClass="txt" placeholder="User Name" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server"
                                                        ControlToValidate="UserName" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="User Name is required."
                                                        ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="AddTeacher"><span class="err I18N">error.messages.User Name is required</span></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </td>

                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="LblPassword" CssClass="lblStyle I18N" runat="server">form.data.Password</asp:Label>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <br />
                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" CssClass="txt" placeholder="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server"
                                                        ControlToValidate="Password" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Password is required."
                                                        ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="AddTeacher"><span class="err I18N">error.messages.Password is required</span></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </td>

                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="LblConfirmPassword" CssClass="lblStyle I18N" runat="server">form.data.Confirm Password</asp:Label>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <br />
                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ConfirmPassword" CssClass="txt" placeholder="Confirm Password" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server"
                                                        ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required."
                                                        ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="AddTeacher"><span class="err I18N">error.messages.Confirm Password is required</span></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </td>

                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="LblEmail" CssClass="lblStyle I18N" runat="server">form.data.Email</asp:Label>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <br />
                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Email" TextMode="SingleLine" CssClass="txt" placeholder="Email"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator18" runat="server"
                                                        ControlToValidate="Email" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Email is required."
                                                        ToolTip="Email is required." ValidationGroup="AddTeacher"><span class="err I18N">error.messages.Email is required</span></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </td>

                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="LblQuestion" CssClass="lblStyle I18N" runat="server">form.data.Question</asp:Label>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <br />
                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Question" CssClass="txt" placeholder="Question" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server"
                                                        ControlToValidate="Question" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Question is required."
                                                        ToolTip="Question is required." ValidationGroup="AddTeacher"><span class="err I18N">error.messages.Question is required</span></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </td>

                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="LblAnswer" CssClass="lblStyle I18N" runat="server">form.data.Answer</asp:Label>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <br />
                                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Answer" TextMode="SingleLine" CssClass="txt" placeholder="Answer"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" runat="server"
                                                        ControlToValidate="Answer" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Answer is required."
                                                        ToolTip="Answer is required." ValidationGroup="AddTeacher"><span class="err I18N">error.messages.Answer is required</span></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                </td>

                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>

                                                <td>

                                                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" runat="server"
                                                        ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" ControlToCompare="Password" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The Password and Confirmation Password must match."
                                                        ToolTip="The Password and Confirmation Password must match." ValidationGroup="AddTeacher"><span class="err I18N">error.messages.PasswordMsg</span></asp:CompareValidator>
                                                </td>

                                            </tr>

                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
                    <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server">
                    </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
                </WizardSteps>
                <NavigationButtonStyle CssClass="navigateButton" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#FFFBD6" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px"
                    Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <CreateUserButtonStyle CssClass="navigateButton" />
                <ContinueButtonStyle CssClass="navigateButton" />
                <SideBarStyle BackColor="White" Font-Size="0.9em" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                <TitleTextStyle BackColor="White" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <SideBarButtonStyle CssClass="navigateButton" />
            </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possibly two things:

You can try using the `FinishDestinationPageUrl` property of the `CreateUserWizard` control. Try setting to empty.

Another is you should handle the `FinishButtonClick` event.
This is fired when finish button is clicked. Basically implement your own logic over there.   So, you can prevent default behavior.